# How to create a Countdown timer that runs even when the app is completely closed?

Tags: java, android-studio, service, timer, countdown

I am trying to create a timer (in a game project) that will countdown 24 hours (even when the user closes the app) and then it will send the user a notification that says the timer finished, but I can't code a Countdown timer that runs when the user closes the app, I have used countdown timer that works with broadcast receiver but it stopped working after the use closed the app completely(probably due to Oreo+ background process limitations).

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Not close to my computer now, so can't write code, but you could do several things.
If you already have some kind of a backend, you could then set up an endpoint that will schedule a notification to the device.
So I guess once the user clicks a buttom, You would send a request to the backend and then after 24 hours, server sends a notification (via Firebase cloud messaging, for example).
That way, you are 100% sure user will receive it no matter whether the app is open or closed.
I suggest that you explore (remote) push notifications.
I hope this helps.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for but I am quit new to programing so I don't know how to code something like this, do you have any examples for this? also I would like to show the user the time that is left, do you know if that's possible to do with your method?

Comment: Well if You have a backend set up, you could then implement firebase push notifications on backend and set up the device to receive them. Also google "local notifications scheduling", there are many pages explaining this topic. Good luck :))